# Why raising NameError when constant removed even if I have set autoload for it?

Tags: ruby, autoload

The following code:

```rb
module P; end

P.autoload(:Foo, "#{__dir__}/foo.rb")
P::Foo.new.foo # works well

P.send(:remove_const, :Foo)
P::Foo.new.foo # raising error
```

I have set the `autoload` for `P::Foo`, but it does not work for second time. Why and How?

Even if I reset the `autoload` it still not works:

```rb
P.send(:remove_const, :Foo)
P.autoload(:Foo, "#{__dir__}/foo.rb")
P::Foo.new.foo # raising error
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the Docs for [`Module#autoload`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Module.html#method-i-autoload):

> Registers filename to be loaded (using Kernel::require) the **first time** that *module* (which may be a String or a symbol) is accessed in the namespace of *mod*.

Per the Docs for [`Kernel#require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require):

> Loads the given `name`, returning `true` if successful and `false` if the feature is already loaded.

You first called the `P::Foo` which "autoloaded" the "#{__dir__}/foo.rb" file via `Kernel#require`. Then you removed the constant `P::Foo` (defined in that file) but the feature was already loaded so the subsequent call does not try and require it again due to the fact that `Kernel.require("#{__dir__}/foo.rb") #=> false`.

This would be identical to an explicit require e.g.

p/foo.rb

```
module P
  class Foo
    def foo; end
  end 
end
```

p.rb

```
module P; end 
require './p/foo' #=> true 

P::Foo.new.foo # works well

P.send(:remove_const, :Foo)

require './p/foo' #=> false
P::Foo.new.foo # raising error
```

If you want to "force" the reloading of that file you can call [`Kernel#load`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-load) instead.